# iphone iOS4 breaking app

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, scale, ios4, nsautoreleasepool

I have an application that has been running fine since its launch over a year ago.

I developed it with iphone iOS 2.2.1 originally and tested and kept selling it up until 3.2 without issues.

Now it fails to launch with iOS4.

the app uses a non standard size for a UIPickerView (I don't think that's the problem but just mention it as you will see some complaint in the console output). It's also giving previously non reported `NSAutoreleasePool` warnings.

But the culprit seems to be when resizing the interface to the new iphone screen resolution (at least what I get from the console)

I know I have to do some research of my own but iOS4 has been out for so little and I have been very absorbed learning and developing my first app for android (so I have not tested this particular code, after a year+ this app only sells a few copies a day) that I thought it didn't harm to ask around here to check if someone has some info or has run into it already.

First, this is the console output when build and run with XCODE 3.2.3 and BASE SDK 3.2, runs without problem

> 2010-06-22 23:25:55.619 metalsandmaterials[82956:207] ******* Accessibility Status Changed: On
>   2010-06-22 23:25:55.710 metalsandmaterials[82956:207] ********** Loading AX for: xxxxxxxxx

But trying to run it with iOS4 gives this beauty:

> 2010-06-22 23:15:52.488 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] ******* Accessibility Status Changed: On
>   2010-06-22 23:15:52.546 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] ********** Loading AX for:   XXXXXXX  ************
>   2010-06-22 23:15:53.003 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] *** -[NSAutoreleasePool release]: This pool has already been released, do not drain it (double release).
>
>   2010-06-22 23:15:53.005 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] *** -[NSAutoreleasePool release]: This pool has already been released, do not drain it (double release).
>   2010-06-22 23:15:53.008 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 50.0 pinned to 162.0

Right here! [UIIageView scale]

> **2010-06-22 23:15:53.011 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] -[UIImageView scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5ac47a0
>
>   2010-06-22 23:15:53.013 metalsandmaterials[80149:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5ac47a0'**
>
> Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x025f5919 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027435de objc_exception_throw + 47
>
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x025f742b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
>
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x02567116 ___forwarding_** + 966
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x02566cd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
>       5   UIKit                               0x0039a8e3 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 250
>       6   UIKit                               0x0039b63e -[UIImageView initWithImage:] + 161
>       7   UIKit                               0x05f286ce -[UIImageViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) initWithImage:] + 70
>       8   metalsandmaterials                  0x0000bf09 -[TVCResults init] + 1841
>       9   metalsandmaterials                  0x00002b8c -[UIVCalcHolder init] + 258
>       10  metalsandmaterials                  0x00002758 -[CalcTestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 649
>       11  UIKit                               0x002d759c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1252
>       12  UIKit                               0x002d99a1 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 346
>       13  UIKit                               0x002e3452 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958
>       14  UIKit                               0x002dc074 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
>       15  UIKit                               0x002e0ac4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7495
>       16  GraphicsServices                    0x02de1afa PurpleEventCallback + 1578
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x025d6dc4   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x02537737 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x025349c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x02534280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x025341a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
>       22  UIKit                               0x002d9226 -[UIApplication _run] + 625
>       23  UIKit                               0x002e4b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>       24  metalsandmaterials                  0x000024ac main + 230
>       25  metalsandmaterials                  0x000023bd start + 53
>       26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
>   Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
>   kill
>   kill

So this `scale` method is new to uiimageview? why wouldn't it work? has anyone run into this already?

ANY HELP IS EXTREMELY APPRECIATED

best regards
david

Comment: This definitely sounds like something you should be filing a bug report with Apple for: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ They really do deal with these fairly quickly.

Comment: The only thing I see in the API Diff in regard to scale is: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/scale

Comment: adrian, will do. david, will read

BUT right now I just did a quick & dirty fix,
- created a MYUIImageView : UIImageView
- added a -(void)scale method that does nothing
- replaced UIImageViews to MYUIImageView

at least it works

I will fill a report and leave this question open for a few days in case anyone else wants to contribute (may help someone else running into this). My interest in fixing this has to do mostly with supporting the people that have already bought the app. By now it does not generate any income worth of too much thought time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I left if at adding a -(void)scale to a subclass of UIImageView and using this new class. Tested it, works fine on 2.2.1, 3.2 and ios4, both on simulator, iphone touch 3g with ios4 and ipad with ios3.2.

I still need to get ahold of an iphone4 and see if some weird layout problem comes across (I still believe the problems appeared when the Os want to blow things up to the new retina display).

Not being in the US is going to make it a tad hard though

Comment: I'm assuming the retina display will only work on apps that have zoom capability.  I doubt they would make it something every app would have to do (sort of how they allow you to turn off rotation).  That would be a headache for everyone to go back and make vector graphics for everything just so it scales nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You get a message "xxxxxx does not recognize selector yyyyyy" usually when an object has been released but you are still trying to use it.  At that point because the memory is random, the system thinks it's some other random kind of object (like UIImage).  Thus it's a red herring, a sign that something else is wrong and you are over-releasing an object.

There's no way you are getting those weird autorelease messages unless you are doing SOMETHING with a custom autorelease pool.  Fess up, what are you doing with an NSAutoreleasePool in your code?

I think they are probably related to the "does not recognize selector" messages since you may be over-releasing things because of this.

Comment: i mentioned below that i had already fixed the autorelease pool and the code was still breaking due to the same reason. and above i did put a quick fix and it's still working (just add a -(void)scale method  to a subclass of UIImageView and use that

unelegant, but works, i still dont know the reason though

Comment: I would look into turning on NSZombieEnabled, since it will tell you what object is actually being called (It's not a UIImage being called)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your first issue with the NSAutoreleasePool, I would use instruments so you can trace where the extra drains/releases are coming from.

Your second issue doesNotRecognizeSelector is telling you that the selector that is being called doesn't exist (or lost scope). I would use the debugger so you can, again, trace that code execution.

Comment: david, the autoreleasepool i have pinned down. no problems there.

and i'm aware there is no scale method for UIImageViews. I do use some CGAffineTransforms around but I removed them just trying to figuring out what is going on

no luck

but why oh why something that worked perfecty on 3.2 would break like this? i would guess that it occurs when the OS tries to sizes things up. But I have no idea right now of what is going on in the background

:(

Appreciate your helps though,
but would love more input

Answer (score 0):

Could I be that you somewhere set the image property of an imageView to another UIImageView (as opposed to an UIImage)?

After all UIImageView does not respond to :scale, but UIImage does.